# Replacing font icons with SVG icon - Remove inline styles

Tags: css, svg, npm, icons

Recently I decided to switch to SVG icons from font icons. I used Illustrator to draw my SVGs and I exported the artboards (containing an individual icon) with the following settings:

- Styling: Inline Style
- Font: SVG
- Images: Embed
- Object IDs: Layer Names
- Decimal: 2

I used the [Icomoon app](https://icomoon.io/) to generate the SVG icons. The problem though is, all the SVGs have a fill, stroke or style property inline everywhere. I can’t update the icon color with CSS while those styles are there in the SVG.

Am I missing something? Is there an option in Illustrator to save the SVG’s without the fill / stroke / styles properties? Or do I have to use something like [Remove SVG Properties](https://github.com/ferdinandtorggler/remove-svg-properties) to remove the properties?

If [Remove SVG Properties](https://github.com/ferdinandtorggler/remove-svg-properties) is the way to go, can someone tell me how to use it in my Angular CLI project? I’m very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Just select the svg in CSS then apply:

```
selector {
    fill: red;
    stroke: blue;
    /* etc */
}
```

It seems to work fine for me.

Optionally, add `!important` if needed.

Another thing you can do to update inline CSS is by jQuery, using `.css()` method.

One way to use free icons from that place is ([link](https://codepen.io/mikele/pen/WZGOYe)):

```css
.lnr-home {
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  /* To get crisp results, use sizes that are
  a multiple of 20; because Linearicons was
  designed on a 20 by 20 grid. */
}

body {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add the following <link> to the <head> of your HTML. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">

<!-- To insert the icon: -->
<span class="lnr lnr-home"></span> lnr-home

<!--
Cheat Sheet:
https://linearicons.com/free#cheatsheet
-->
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work when the svg has something like this: `<path fill="#637282" style="fill: var(--color1, #637282)" d="..."></path>`. If you get rid of the `fill="#637282" style="fill: var(--color1, #637282)"` only does the style you added above works.

Comment: If you update the inline values from inspect, do the colors change? If yes, then update values from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use online tool 
this is automatically convert inline style.
use this android developer
http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/